# How to rebind jQuery Color box after some items have been filtered

Tags: jquery, bind, live, colorbox

A have a galeria of items that shows a bigger picture after clicking.
But after filtering some elements (using `.hide()`), the ColorBox slideshow keeps showing all elements.

I've tried to use:

```
$('.colorbox').die().live('click', function() {
  $.fn.colorbox({href:$(this).attr('href'), open:true});
  return false;
}
```

But it does show the slideshow with all the items in the `rel` only the item clicked.

**How can I rebind all the items not filtered?**

Comment: Could you show the initial selector for the colorbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried removing the rel attribute when hiding the filtered elements?
You can do this in jquery using removeAttr

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add the :visible pseudo-class selector to your colour box selector (untested)?:

```
$('.colorbox:visible').die().live('click', function() {
  $.fn.colorbox({href:$(this).attr('href'), open:true});
  return false;
}
```

Comment: No, does not solve it. The problem is that only show 1 photo (not the slideshow)